# Proving $\frac{m-n}{(m+1)(n+1)}=\frac{1}{k}$ for every $k>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can we show that for any integer $k>1$ there are positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$\frac{1}{k}=\frac{m-n}{(m+1)(n+1)}.$$

(Thanks to Arthur Fischer for the reformulation!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false for $k=2$. For $k$ not $2$, $\frac{1}{k}=\frac{(k(k-1)-1)-(k-2)}{k(k-1)(k-1)}$.